# Иконка во вкладке

Tags: html, html5

Не могу сделать на html5 иконку во вкладке, которая обычно отображается, не получается так:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Какой-то странный тип .з. Он, если мне не изменяет память, для .ico файлов. Может, его лучше вообще убрать?)

Comment: А как тогда вообще сделать, раньше получалось и с .png, только не помню как. Подскажите, как сделать.

Comment: Если файл на месте - попробуйте убрать спецификатор типа файла - он некорректный.

Comment: Что-то нефига не выходит! =(

Comment: @iwowa Уважаемый участник, не надо использовать без надобности восклицательные знаки.

Comment: Лодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Иконка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon):

> Для явного указания местоположения favicon.ico необходимо вписать cледующую строку в код страницы вашего сайта внутрь секции head:
>
> `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/someimage.png" />`

Если не цепляется, то

1. проверить пути (положить в корень),
2. проверить разные форматы и размеры (png, ico и тп.),
3. проверить разные браузеры (IE или Chrome),
4. проверить соответствие type (type="image/png" для png).